# Why is my app launching the wrong activities?

Tags: android, button, android-activity, click, launch

I have play buttons on custom popups and they are taking me to the wrong activity and im not sure why. The activity its launching is not even in the onclick method.

```
    Button playit = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.playDetourDialog);
        playit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("go to pyramid");
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PyramidGamePlay.class);
                startActivity(i);
                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        });
```

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".Main"
              android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:name="GamePlayRegular"></activity>
    <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:name="WorldSelect"></activity>
    <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:name="OptionsPage"></activity>
    <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:name="World"></activity>
    <activity android:name="GameEndPage" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"></activity>
    <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:name="PyramidGamePlay"></activity>

</application>
```

Comment: please past your code and manifest.xml file.

Comment: can u post other part of your code..?

Comment: what other part of my code do you want? it is a relatively large project so there is a lot of code but that should start the right activity no?

Comment: can you post your error logcat?

Comment: I figured it out. it was a dumb mistake. i put a new launch in the onpause to prevent an error a while ago and forgot about it. thanks for you help guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use like this

```
<activity android:name="PyramidGameplay">

         <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to know without more information.  Have you defined your activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml`?  What info does `logcat` print when you tap the `playit` button?

It would also be good to use the `android.util.log` package for logging, rather than using `System.out.println`.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm obviously new here and was just trying to help out.  Plus I'd say that pointing out that @Robin should use `android.util.log` should count for something. 